# How to run a hide function and an animation when document.ready(function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

this is my first question because I can't find a similar one.
So, I try to hide some elements when my page is ready and also an animation. It just doesn't work. Sorry for my English and I'm also very new to Jquery. Here you see the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mainbox-search-main").show();
   $("#mainbox-search-extra").hide();
   $("#mainbox-login").hide();
   $("#mainbox-register").hide();
   $("#mainbox-pasfor").hide();
   $(".fab").animate({
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 1s
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) /* Safari */
      transform: rotate(180deg)
   });
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Nothing is hidden, nothing is animated, or both? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Might be helpful to post your page or a jsfiddle

Comment: When I add the animate function. The others doesnt work anymore.

Comment: With animation: https://gyazo.com/5f74132a1b0dd0de5289230fad060169
Without animation: https://gyazo.com/399a0711f9f1859a51548ea09a99daf1

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to replicate it without a JSFiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net

However, to make it easier on yourself just add a class with those properties:

**JQuery**

```
$(".fab").addClass('animate-it');
```

**CSS**

```
.animate-it{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 1s
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) /* Safari */
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) /* Firefox */
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

In addition, you don't really need to hide any elements when the document is being loaded. Just initially set those displays to `none`.

```
#mainbox-search-extra, #mainbox-login, #mainbox-register, #mainbox-pasfor{
  display:none;
}
```

When you want to show them, just use the `show()` method that you have used for the `#mainbox-search-main` element.

**Addressing Unnecessary Lag Time**

I also want to point out that you may want to add a delay to the animation in case there is some undesired lag time between when the animation fires, and the DOM is considered to be loaded.

```
$(".fab").delay(500).addClass('animate-it');
```

**Conclusion: Adding a Callback Function**

With the hidden elements being taken care of in the CSS, we have a shorter amount of code to work with. To ensure that the animate happens AFTER the `#mainbox-search-main` element is shown, try adding a callback function to it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mainbox-search-main").show(function(){
      $(".fab").delay(500).addClass('animate-it');
   });
});
```